# Line breaks when the browsers windows is not in maximum mode

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am trying to design (responsive) a website that will appear perfectly in every devices. I am using blueprint CSS framework (converted to fluid) I have the following codes for a simple heading.

HTML

```
<div class="prepend-3" style="margin-top:20px;">
   <h1>Stack <span style="color:#C6CBCE">Overflow</span></h1>
</div>
```

MY CSS

```
h1 { 
   padding: 20px 0; margin: 0; 
   font-family: "Trebuchet MS", serif; 
   font-size: 9em; color: #222; 
   font-weight: normal; 
   line-height: 80px; }
```

The problem I am facing is when I run the code keeping my browsers window to maximum mode I can see both the words "stack" and "overflow" are in same line which is perfect, but when I don't maximize my browser's window, the line breaks down like following .

Could you please tell me how to fix this problem (make it responsive)?

Thanks :)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `white-space: nowrap;` property

```
h1 { 
   padding: 20px 0; 
   margin: 0; 
   font-family: "Trebuchet MS", serif; 
   font-size: 9em; 
   color: #222; 
   font-weight: normal; 
   line-height: 80px;
   white-space: nowrap; <------Here
}
```

Or to be precise you can also specify different styles specific to screen sizes using CSS3 @media queries like, but I expect you are using this as you've specified `Responsive`

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
 /* Styles Goes Here */  
}
```